# Lodash SortBy with Nested Objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, lodash, semantic-ui

I'm pulling data from the eBay API and trying to display the data in a table with the ability for the user to sort the columns. Fields that are nested are not being sorted properly and I can't figure out how to do it.

Some of the fields I want to show are nested objects. I'm trying to sort by the `watchCount` field, which you can see below is a field within `listingInfo`.

```
 {
    itemId: [
        "323992063737"
    ],
    title: [
        "1909-11 T206 George Perring Sweet Caporal 350/30 PSA 2"
    ],
    listingInfo: [
    {
    bestOfferEnabled: [
        "false"
    ],
    buyItNowAvailable: [
        "false"
    ],
    startTime: [
        "2019-11-25T18:37:33.000Z"
    ],
    endTime: [
        "2019-12-25T18:37:33.000Z"
    ],
    listingType: [
        "FixedPrice"
    ],
    gift: [
        "false"
    ],
    watchCount: [
        "1"
    ]
}
```

I'm following this [Semantic UI React example](https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/table/#variations-sortable) to create a sortable table.  But for the deeply nested items, such as `watchCount` it isn't working.

My code looks similar to Semantic UI code, yet I'm adding a handler to turn the strings into integers.  The sort works on the title field, but not on the other ones (such as `watchCount`)

```
  const [column, setColumn] = useState(null);
  const [direction, setDirection] = useState(null);
  const [filteredData, setData] = useState(props.cardsToShow);

  console.log("CARDS TO SHOW", props.cardsToShow);
  console.log("TYPE OF", typeof cardsToShow);
  console.log("Filtered Data Before", filteredData);
  console.log("column", column);
  console.log("direction", direction);

  const handleSortNumeric = clickedColumn => {
    const sorter = data => parseInt(data[clickedColumn]);
    setData(_.sortBy(filteredData, sorter));
    console.log("sorted", _.sortBy(filteredData, sorter));
  };

  const handleSortReverse = () => {
    const sorter = data => parseInt(data);
    setData(_.sortBy(filteredData, sorter).reverse());
    console.log("reverse sorted", _.sortBy(filteredData, sorter).reverse());
  };

  const handleSort = clickedColumn => {
    if (column !== clickedColumn) {
      setColumn(clickedColumn);
      if (clickedColumn === "title") {
        setData(_.sortBy(filteredData, [clickedColumn]));
        console.log("Filtered After", filteredData);
      } else {
        handleSortNumeric(clickedColumn);
        console.log("Filtered After", filteredData);
      }
      setDirection("ascending");
      return;
    }

    if (clickedColumn === "title") {
      setData(_.sortBy(filteredData.reverse()));
    } else {
      handleSortReverse();
    }

    direction === "ascending"
      ? setDirection("descending")
      : setDirection("ascending");
  };
```

And this is what an example header on my table looks like:

```
  <Table.HeaderCell
                sorted={column === "watch" ? direction : null}
                onClick={() => handleSort("watch")}
              >
```

I'm confused on all of this, but is my initial assumption that the nested data is causing the issue here? Or is it something else entirely?

Comment: Well, i solved this by structuring my data properly on the backend, so that I wouldn't have to fool around with all of the nested data on the front end.  The main issue was that my column header names were not matching up with the names of the actual data fields.  Just in case someone runs into a similar issue.